# Infinite family of left ideals $J$ in a matrix ring $R$ and their direct sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This exercise is from a previous exam.

Let $R = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbb{Z} & 0 \\ \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}\end{bmatrix}$ and $I = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Z} & 0 \\ \mathbb{Z} & 0\end{bmatrix}$ be a left ideal of $R$. Find an infinite number of left ideals $J$ in $R$ such that $R = I \oplus J$

Firstly, I don't know exactly what they're asking me to do. If I find an infinite number of left ideals $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $R = I \oplus (J_1 \oplus J_2 \oplus ...)$, would that be correct? Or is it more likely that I'm supposed to find $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $R = I \oplus J_i$ for all $i=1,2,...$?

I tried to construct the left ideals $J$ like this: $J_p = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 &\mathbb{Z}p\end{bmatrix}$ for all the primes $p$, but then the infinite sum $I + J_2 + J_3 + J_5 + ...$ isn't direct, and the direct sum $I \oplus J_p \neq R$. I'm not sure how I should construct the $J$'s to solve this, and it doesn't help that I don't know exactly what I'm suposed to be solving.

I would very much appreciate some small hints on how to solve this, and which of the two direct sums you think is the one they're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't far off. You can't get around having $\mathbb Z$ in the lower right hand corner though: after subtracting elements in $I$, you have to be able to get anything in the lower right corner.

Try ideals of the form $R\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\p&1\end{bmatrix}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\np&n\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\, n\in\mathbb Z\right\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I might be misunderstanding, but I have a question about your suggested ideals. Let's call the ideal you suggested $J$ for some prime number $p$, wouldn't the intersection $I \cap J \neq (0)$ because of the elements in the lower left hand corner of $J$? And wouldn't this imply that the sum isn't direct?

Also, should the two non-zero elements in that ideal have the common factor $n$? It seems to me that they could have different factors $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Auclair For your first question: something in the intersection would look like $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\np&n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{bmatrix}$. Look at what this tells you about $n$.  As for your second question: of course they should have the common factor $n$. Look at the definition of the principal left ideal $R\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\p&1\end{bmatrix}$. This is the very thing we are exploiting to prove directness! If we had $mp$ instead of $np$, how would we prove $b=mp=0$?

Comment: Yes, now that it's clear that they must have the common factor $n$ the intersection question almost answers itself. Thank you!